# Page not displaying results from datastore query, using jinja2 and python. Help finding issue?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2

When I load the html page the results from the database are not appearing.  I am using python and jinja2.  The {{ initial_city }} is displaying the correct results, the problem seems to be with get_deals or on the html file where I have used jinja2.  I want to display results that equal to the city chosen on the main page (it is a form).  Also, I have entities in the database, which appear when going onto the google datastore local extension

the get_deals code is:

```
    def get(self):
        def get_deals(choose_city, update=False):
            key = str(choose_city)
            all_deals = memcache.get(key)
            if all_deals is None:
                d = Deal.all()
                all_deals = d.filter('city = ', choose_city)
                all_deals = list(all_deals)
                memcache.set(key, all_deals)
           return all_deals
```

Below are my scripts:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.ext.db import stats
from models import Deal
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2



class Deal(db.Model):
   title = db.TextProperty()
   description = db.TextProperty()
   city = db.TextProperty()

 deal = Deal(title='Hello',
        #description='Deal info here',
        #city='New York')
 deal.put()



jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
      self.response.out.write(template.render())


class DealHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        def get_deals(choose_city, update=False):
            key = str(choose_city)
            all_deals = memcache.get(key)
            if all_deals is None:
                d = Deal.all()
                all_deals = d.filter('city = ', choose_city)
                all_deals = list(all_deals)
                memcache.set(key, all_deals)
           return all_deals


    choose_city = self.request.get('c')
    try:
        initial_city = str(choose_city)
        choose_city = initial_city
    except ValueError:
        initial_city = 0
        choose_city = initial_city


    template = jinja_environment.get_template('deal.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(initial_city = initial_city, get_deals = get_deals))



    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/deal', DealHandler),
                           ('/content', ContentHandler)],
                          debug=True)
```

And my html page that is not displaying the results is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-      v2/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<title>
Deallzz: Chosen City: {{ initial_city }}
</title>
</head>
<body>
All deals:

{% for deal in deals %}
<li>{{ get_deals }}</li>
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using `deals` in your template, but passing `get_deals`. Try changing line in `response.out.write` with `self.response.out.write(template.render(initial_city = initial_city, deals = get_deals(choose_city)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your code you are not calling `get_deals` function. I would suggest you to take `get_deals()` out of `get()` and call it like

   ```
   self.response.out.write(template.render(initial_city = initial_city, get_deals =self.get_deals(choose_city)))
   ```

   because it is a good design.

   **EDIT**
   Change `self.get_deals()` to 'get_deals()` if you do not plan to do so.
2. You use `deals` in your html but is not specifying its value when calling from the server. 
   Probably what you want to do is

   ```
   {% for deal in get_deals %}    
       {{ deal }}  
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Comment: I edited the python code and I now get the error "AttributeError: 'DealHandler' object has no attribute 'get_deals'"

Comment: I edited the python code and I now get the error "AttributeError: 'DealHandler' object has no attribute 'get_deals'"

Also, for the html file, can i simply us {{ get_deals }} to display the results, or is the {% ? %} required?

Comment: see the edit. You need to make `get_deals()` a class function to do call it like the way I said. Ppl usually modularize their code this way and I thought even you did the same.

Comment: Thanks Emil, almost there I think.  The error message is now "TypeError: get_deals() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)"

I dont think I need the if statement within this code, but Im not sure how to correct it:
def get(self):
        def get_deals(choose_city, update=False):
            key = str(choose_city)
            all_deals = memcache.get(key)
            if all_deals is None:
                d = Deal.all()
                all_deals = d.filter('city = ', choose_city)
                all_deals = list(all_deals)
                memcache.set(key, all_deals)
           return all_deals

Comment: Hey, sorry. I am still trying to figure it out.  The python code is right now.  Just having trouble with jinja2 templating. it is outputting ' [] ' only.  I guess i could move the jinja2 question to a new thread.

Comment: did you  try the template code I provided? You are printing the list as such. If the list is empty it prints `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually calling the get_deals function.

Comment: Can you explain further? Should I be calling the all_deals instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could try inserting

```
get_deals = get_deals(choose_city)
```

before

```
self.response.out.write(template.render(initial_city = initial_city, get_deals = get_deals))
```

What Emil suggests should work as well. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: With both trys i get [] as the output?

Comment: This is probably an artifact of stackoverflow, but I think that your indentation is not quite right. 
choose_city = self.request.get('c') and the code underneath it should be in line with your definition of the get_deals function.